# Qgis 2.99 3D map view

Tags: qgis, symbology, 3d

In QGIS 2.99 I created a 3D scene with buildings, etc. I added small spheres (with 3D rendering) with xyz coordinates to create a grid of spheres around a building. Now I am wondering if it's possible to set the color of these spheres depending on a certain value?